# How i can use the id in the textbox from a moda form to do query using php and mysql to fill out the value of other textbox

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I had a form table and For the edit button, when i click the button the modal will come out.

[image: Table]

[image]

The problem is how i can use the id in the textbox to do query using php and mysql to fill out the value of other textbox.

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//jquery funtion to sent id to Edit modal
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#modalEditGroup').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
     $('#id').val(id);
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<input type="button" id="edit-group" name="edit-group" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-id="<?php echo $row['group_id'];?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditGroup" value="Edit">


<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalEditGroup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <!-- Modal Header -->
         <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close"
                 data-dismiss="modal">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                     <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
              </button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                  Edit Group
              </h4>
         </div>

         <!-- Modal Body -->
         <div class="modal-body">

              <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label  class="col-sm-4 control-label">Id</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" class="id" />
                     </div>
                   </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label  class="col-sm-4 control-label">Group Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                       <input type="text" id="group_name_edit" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value=""  name="group_name_edit">
                  </div>
                </div>


               <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Access Level</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                   <input type="text" id="access_level_edit" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value=""  name="access_level_edit">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Approve By</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                   <input type="text" id="approve_by_edit" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value=""  name="approve_by_edit">
                  </div>
                </div>




                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset">Reset</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </form>

         </div>

         <!-- Modal Footer -->

      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way as setting `id` in `#id` field like,

```
$('#modalEditGroup').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var t=$(e.relatedTarget),
      id = t.data('id'),
      gname=t.data('gname'),
      alevel=t.data('alevel'),
      appby=t.data('appby');
     $('#id').val(id);
     $('#group_name_edit').val(gname);
     $('#access_level_edit').val(alevel);
     $('#approve_by_edit').val(appby);
});
```

Add `data-*` in HTML like,

```
<input type="button" id="edit-group" name="edit-group" 
   class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" 
   data-id="<?php echo $row['group_id'];?>" 
   data-gname="<?php echo $row['group_name'];?>" 
   data-alevel="<?php echo $row['access_level'];?>"
   data-appby="<?php echo $row['approve_by'];?>" 
   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditGroup" 
   value="Edit" />
```

And add on submit event like,

```
$('#submit').on('click',fucntion(){
   $.ajax({
      url:'YOUR-URL-TO-SUBMIT-DATA',
      type:'post',
      data:{
          id:$('#id').val(),group_name:$('#group_name_edit').val(),
          access_level:$('#access_level_edit').val(),
          approve_by:$('#approve_by_edit').val()
      },
      success:function(data){
          // check for success and error messages
          // if success then hide modal box and alert('Success'); 
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On click of edit button before showing the modal, make an `ajax` call the `ID` and get the details of associated with that `ID` and fill it to the `modal` elements and than show the modal.

Ex:

```
$('#modalEditGroup').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
     var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
     // make ajax() call here with the id
     // fill the response in the the modal
     // show the modal
});
```